# Set 'DiscardPolicy' on 'ThreadPool' created using 'ExecuteOnExecutor' method

Tags: android

I have a class called `LoadEncryptedImage` and that is derived from `AsyncTask`.
I used the below code to execute the async tasks in parallel,

```
        LoadEncryptedImage loadEncryptedImage = new LoadEncryptedImage(mContext, eventMember.MemberPhotoURL,
                viewHolder.imgUser);
        loadEncryptedImage.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

It works properly, but it throws `RejectedExecutionException` if the tasks exceeds the limit of the `ThreadPool`. I want to set `DiscardPolicy` on `ThreadPool` to discard the issue silently. But how we can do this on a `Threadpool` created using `ExecuteOnExecutor` method.

Comment: don't use AsyncTask.

Comment: Hi, I have to call web services for downloading encrypted images, I want to do that without blocking the UI, do you recommend any other alternatives for AsyncTask?

Comment: I will search on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how we can do this on a Threadpool created using ExecuteOnExecutor method.

That is not a good idea. Do not change the characteristics of a thread pool that you did not create, as other things that depend upon that thread pool may not appreciate the changes that you make.

Instead, create your own `ThreadPoolExecutor`, with your desired characteristics, and pass that into `executeOnExecutor()`.

Comment: I will try to implement my own ThreadPoolExecutor for this purpose. Thanks